# Java UTF-8 Malformed Test Case is Right?

Tags: java, utf-8

I am going through the JDK test code to see how they validate their UTF8.encode() works as expected since we have similar cases. Some test cases which I don't fully understand why it's invalid.

1. `(byte)0xC0, (byte)0x80}`, // invalid first byte

https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-jdk/blob/master/test/sun/nio/cs/TestUTF8.java#L276

the binary is `11000000 10000000` which suits the format of  2bytes utf8: `110xxxxx 10xxxxxx`

2. (byte)0xE0, (byte)0x80, (byte)0x80 }, // U+0000 zero-padded

https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-jdk/blob/master/test/sun/nio/cs/TestUTF8.java#L287

Binary is `11100000 10000000 10000000` which also looks like a good 3 bytes utf8 encoded.

Can anyone help me understand it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UTF-8 requires that the shortest possible sequence be used for a codepoint.

Anything starting with 0xc0 represents a codepoint which is in the 00000 000000 – 00000 ffffff range, which is 0–63 decimal, which means it can be expressed as a single byte.  In other words, any 11000000 10yyyyyy encoding is properly encoded as just 00yyyyyy.

The same goes for 0xe0 0x80 0x80.

From [the UTF-8 specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3629#section-3):

> Implementations of the decoding algorithm above MUST protect against
> decoding invalid sequences.  For instance, a naive implementation may
> decode the overlong UTF-8 sequence C0 80 into the character U+0000,
> or the surrogate pair ED A1 8C ED BE B4 into U+233B4.  Decoding
> invalid sequences may have security consequences or cause other
> problems.

Answer (score 3):

i imagine that the objection is that it's not canonical.

C0, 80  results in 11 bits of zero for the Unicode character, which is U+0000.   That ought to have been encoded as one byte of zero.

Similarly for the second example.

The UTF-8 standard requires the shortest-length encoding.